# either SET and SETX do not set the value of %PATH%

Tags: windows, path, batch-file, cmd

I'm executing the following command

```
SETX PATH "very_very_long_list";
```

after closing and opening comand line, `echo %path%` outputs the old value. What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you opening a new command line? Unless the process launching the new command line is listening for environment change events it will not refresh its environment (and thus that of new child processes). Explorer does listen. PS. It works here.

Comment: Environment variables are per-process.  The registry variables that `setx` sets probably don't take effect until you log on again.

Comment: Variables set using SETX are only available in future command windows and not in the current command window. They're not per-process as @asveikau said, nor do you need to log out and in again, just start a new command window -- although it sounds like you're doing that, so it's unclear what you're doing wrong. Perhaps it's the unneeded quotes and the trailing semicolon.

Comment: @martineau - Environment variables are certainly per-process.  What I meant to say is that `setx` won't modify the environment of a running process - you have to start a new one for it to take effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `SETX PATH`. If you need to add onto the current `PATH`, use

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\another path\;C:\yet\another path\
```

Else if you need to wipe PATH completely and then add in your own parameters use

```
PATH=C:\path\;C:\another path\;C:\yet\another path\
```

No need to surround paths with double quotes as `PATH` command sees spaces in pathnames.

Comment: The semicolons `;` at the very end aren't necessary.

Comment: AFAIK, this answer does not set it permanently, which is what the OP wants. 
You'll need to use SETX (to be permanent) and SET (to see the changes immediatly). See http://batcheero.blogspot.pt/2008/02/set-and-setx.html